# Guide to setup aws ETL glue pyspark job by step by step

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-lambda

I am beginner for AWS pipelines.

**Input** I recieve `csvs` tables in S3 buckets `RAW_input` For example- `folder1` contains `sales.csv` and `customer.csv` and same for `folder2`.

**Transformation** Then we need to apply `tested` `query` `(SQLsfiles are in S3)` and apply `mapping + structure cleaning` `(Glue Jobs)` such as int change, data format change etc. for `each` table in buckets and setting up `output` in required `destination`.

**Destination:** Output of the `queries` is expected in `redshift tables`. (We have clusters and database ready for it).

**Req** I would like to setup a pyspark glue job that trigger automatically when any file uploaded into S3 bucket.

**Questions**

1. Can only Glue job can do all work such as `input s3 trigger`+ `SQl mapping` + `cleaning` ?

I can't have User `secret access keys` so I have to work only inside the AWS service by access roles and policy. **NO CI/CD solution needed**

Please relavent comments only if you need some explaination.

I tried: **But i prefer looping over different Athena SQL files in S3 over same `csv`. For example sales.sql run over sales.csv and send data to redshift**

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

# EXTRACT: Reading parquet data
df = spark.read.format("csv").load('s3://<bucket_name>/<file_path>/<file_name>.csv')

# TRANSFORM: some transformation
df = df.distinct()

# LOAD: write data to Redshift
df.write.format("jdbc").\
    option("url", "jdbc:redshift://<host>:5439/<database>").\
    option("dbtable", "<table_schema>.<table_name>").\
    option("user", "<username>").\
    option("password", "<password>").\
    mode('overwrite').save()
    
print("Data Loaded to Redshift")
```

Answer (score -1):

I'll try to answer  directly your questions:

**Can only Glue job can do all work such as input s3 trigger+ mapping + cleaning ?**

> A trigger starts the ETL job execution on-demand or at a specific time.

**Do I still need to develop aws lambda function in this process to trigger glue job?**

> Nope

**Allocation of query trigger per selected table by job sounds a tough work.**

> With the final tables in place, you can create Glue Jobs, which can be run on a schedule, on a trigger, or on-demand. A job is business logic that carries out an ETL task. So you create  job based on a selection of tables and not a job per table.

**clusters in AWS glue are created manually, I don't know its the only way to do it or not.**

> AWS Glue is simply a serverless ETL tool, you don't need to manage clusters, you don't create clusters manually.

**Any References / github codes for pyspark can be helpful**

> https://aws.amazon.com/glue/getting-started/
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/index.html
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/trigger-job.html